# How can I get JSON.parse result covered by the Flow type checker?

Tags: json, flowtype

I'm new to working with flow. I'm trying to get as close to 100% flow coverage as possible on a project, and one thing I can't figure out is how to handle is `JSON.parse`.

```
type ExampleType = {
  thingOne: boolean,
  thingTwo: boolean,
};
const exampleVariable: ExampleType = JSON.parse(
  '{thingOne: true, thingTwo: false}'
);
```

So I have a type, and I receive a string from another source, and I parse it and expect it to be of that type.

The whole `JSON.parse(...)` section is marked as "Not covered by flow".

Is there a way to get a file to 100% flow coverage if `JSON.parse` is used in that file? How? What exactly is flow saying when it says that line isn't covered?

Comment: It can't tell whether your assignment is actually valid.

Comment: A static(!) code checking tool cannot check anything that happens during runtime. The result of `JSON.parse` is `mixed` because it cannot be determined statically.

Comment: So there isn't a way to get 100% coverage in a file with `JSON.parse`, because flow can't know if the string being parsed will result into the right type?

Comment: Yes there is, you have to add code for RUNTIME checks, which Flow will recognize as type refinements. https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/

Comment: Anyway - "100% coverage" is like "100% perfect", anyone even attempting it _for anything nontrivial_ does not understand how the universe works. When you get there (to 100% perfection) the rest of the universe is already dead. Play some StarCraft II to get the "perfection" idea out of you (in favor of actually getting things done).

Comment: The plan is definitely to use flow to get things done! I'm just spending the day trying to get a handful of files to 100% as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `JSON.parse` returns `any`. Here is the signature:

```
static parse(text: string, reviver?: (key: any, value: any) => any): any;
```

Flow cannot guarantee that the assignment of the parse result to the type `ExampleType` is correct because who knows what will come out when you parse incoming JSON?

But you can get coverage to 100% if you parse with [flow-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-validator) instead. When parsing a string as far as Flow knows that string could have come from anywhere. So there is no static guarantee that the JSON data in the string has the shape that you expect. What flow-validator does it to provide an API to describe a validation schema for your data instead of a type. The schema is checked at runtime while parsing. Flow-validator automatically generates a static type from your schema, and assigns the result from a successful parse to that type. Here is what your example looks like with flow-validator:

```
import { boolean, object } from "flow-validator"

const ExampleSchema = object({
  thingOne: boolean,
  thingTwo: boolean
})

const exampleVariable = ExampleSchema.parse(
  '{"thingOne": true, "thingTwo": false}'
)
```

You can check and see that Flow infers the correct type for `exampleVariable`, and your Flow coverage is now at 100%. If the JSON data does not have the correct shape then `ExampleSchema.parse` will throw an error.

You can get a type from the schema like this:

```
type ExampleType = typeof ExampleSchema.type
```

This version of `ExampleType` is just like the one in your original example. Extracting a type automatically saves you from having to write the shape for your data structure twice, and it also guarantees that the static type stays in sync with the runtime validation schema.