# TypeError: class.function is not a function. (In 'classname.function(param)')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype, ecmascript-5

I'm not an expert to JavaScript, but following the logic of languages like Java and others a the following should work, but does not:

```
//* @flow */

class Assets {
  parts: Array<PartsItem>;

  constructor() {
    this.parts = [];
  }

  merge(other: Assets) {
    this.parts = this.parts.concat(other.parts);
  }
}

class PartsItem {
  name: string;
}

function addNewAssets(assets: Assets, newAssets: Assets) {
  // the out log verifies that both assets are having all expected values and expected structure
  console.log("adding ", newAssets);
  console.log("to ", assets);
  assets.merge(newAssets);
  return assets;
}

function run_example() {
  let item1: PartsItem = new PartsItem();
  item1.name = "part1";
  let item2: PartsItem = new PartsItem();
  item2.name = "part2";

  let assets = new Assets();
  let otherAssets = new Assets();

  assets.parts.push(item1);
  otherAssets.parts.push(item1);

  let mergedAssets = addNewAssets(assets, otherAssets);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(mergedAssets));
}

run_example();
```

when calling addNewAssets I would expect to get merged assets as the result, but the result is:

```
[12:06:55] W | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
                             │ TypeError: assets.merge is not a function. (In 'assets.merge(newAssets)', 'assets.merge' is undefined)
```

Does it have anything to do with JS "unpredictable" *this*?

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript to me. Is it TypeScript?

Comment: "when calling addNewAssets" — You aren't calling it in the code you provided. You need a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin: its JavaScript with Flow

Comment: @Quentin: you can run the code example in: https://flow.org/try

Comment: Just checked the code in the question and it works as expected. The only thing is: instead of `this.parts.concat(other.parts)` I'd expect `this.parts = this.parts.concat(other.parts)`;

Comment: thanks @AlexSavin, I had already implemented a method outside of the class and also came across this bug. But this is actually not the issue, why I java script keep on saing that the class function merge is not a function :/

Answer (score 1):

Even when some *very smart folks* has downgraded that question, it is showcasing a pitfall with JS classes and Flow.

Since the assets has been used after being read back from JSON some class information has get lost, even tho the fields has been typed, Flow is not Java and not hard typed.

I'll need to try this: https://github.com/STRML/json-to-flow 
or https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-validator as described here:
[How can I get JSON.parse result covered by the Flow type checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335934/how-can-i-get-json-parse-result-covered-by-the-flow-type-checker)